# Trying to remove markers in layerGroup with Mapbox

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox

I'm new to `mapbox`. This seems like it should be simple but I can't seem to `clearLayers()` successfully on my `layerGroup`. Code in ajax success handler:

```
var _this = this,
    len = data.places.length,
    markers = [];

for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {

    var latlng = L.latLng(data.places[i].place_lat, data.places[i].place_lng);
    var marker = L.marker(latlng)
       .bindPopup('<h2><a href="http://website.com/place/' + data.places[i].place_id + '" target="_blank">' +
            data.places[i].place_name + '</a></h2>')
       .addTo(_this.map);

    markers.push(marker);
}

if (_this.layerGroup) {
    _this.layerGroup.clearLayers();
}

_this.layerGroup = new L.layerGroup(markers);
```

When the success handler is called the second and third time etc. I'd like to just clear out the layerGroup (remove all markers) and reuse it again.

EDIT: Instead of clearLayers I also tried this which found the layers but did not remove the markers

```
            if(_this.layerGroup){
                _this.layerGroup.eachLayer(function(layer){
                    _this.layerGroup.removeLayer(layer);
                })
            }
```

EDIT: Relevant line from below: **_this.map**.removeLayer(layer);
This successfully removed the markers but it does not match the examples I've looked at. Seems my layerGroup isn't associated with my maps which is the next thing I need to solve.

```
            if(_this.layerGroup){
                _this.layerGroup.eachLayer(function(layer){
                    _this.map.removeLayer(layer);
                })
            }
```

Comment: Move `_this = this` outside of the success handler.

Comment: Thanks. I'm binding to the appropriate scope when listening for the submit handler on my form: $('#setCity').on('submit', this.handleMapboxSearch.bind(this));

Comment: just realized that doesn't speak to the ajax handler... well in handleMapboxSearch I setup my ajax request and success handler

Answer (score 0):

First time playing with mapbox so made a stupid mistake but found the solution:

```
            var _this = this,
                len = data.places.length,
                markers = [];

            if(_this.layerGroup){
                _this.layerGroup.clearLayers();
            }

            _this.layerGroup = new L.LayerGroup().addTo(_this.map);

            for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {

                var latlng = L.latLng( data.places[i].place_lat,  data.places[i].place_lng);
                var marker = L.marker(latlng)
                   .bindPopup('<h2><a href="http://website.com//place/' + data.places[i].place_id + '" target="_blank">' +
                        data.places[i].place_name + '</a></h2>')
                   .addTo(_this.layerGroup);

                markers.push(marker);
            }
```

The *layerGroup* should be added to the *map* and the *markers* to the *layerGroup*. I've refactored to make it clear. I can now use clearLayers properly.

Comment: I will also be using FeatureGroup instead of LayerGroup as FeatureGroup extends LayerGroup and provides mouse events